# Java assigning Set of Interface

Tags: java, interface, set

I think this is simple question, but I stuck on it.
I am trying to assign one Set to another:

```
Set<Registrable> rr =kart.getReg();
```

where kart.getReg() return Set of Reg:

```
public class Kart {
public Set<Reg> getReg() {
    return reg;
}
...
```

but "Registrable" is an interface, defined like:

```
 public interface Registrable  {
    getters...
    setters...
 }
```

and finally the class "Reg" is:

```
 public class Reg implements Registrable {
    getters...
    setters...
 }
```

and my compiler wrote:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Set<Reg> to Set<Registrable>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Generics let you enforce compile-time type safety on Collections.

So you can't use -

`Set<Registrable> rr =kart.getReg();`

But you can use wildcard like the following.

```
Set<? extends Registrable> rr = kart.getReg();
```

Notice  -  you **can't add items** to the Set rr.

For example -

```
rr.add(someItems); //will give you compile error.
```

If you want to **add items** to the Set, you can use the following.

```
Set<? super Reg> rr = kart.getReg();
```

It can accept **Reg and it's supper classes** and you can use **rr.add(someItems)** without compile error.